# Creating a Mobile User Interface for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to make an HTML interface for a spreadsheet that doesn't run inside the spreadsheet? Basically I want to use the spreadsheet as a simple database.

I can't seem to find a way to do it in the documentation. I got this to work this way:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
ss.show(html);
```

That opens my page automatically when I load the sheet, which is not a bad way to have it work, but I would rather run it from a separate page without having to know it is looking at a spreadsheet.

Also, this script doesn't work on mobile browsers which is an issue.

Is what I want to do possible currently? I have been looking at the documentation for a while without a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will be wanting to deploy your script as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps), rather than a "container-bound" script inside a spreadsheet.

As there will be no spreadsheet inherently associated with the web app, you would need to use the [openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById%28String%29) method rather than getActive().

Comment: Adam, I think this answer's on the right track, but the OP would already be deploying as a web app, to get HtmlService to work - any script, even container-bound, can do that. The distinction you're going for is that the script should be "[standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_containers#standalone)".

Comment: Ah thanks +Mogsdad, yes the "standalone" link would be more appropriate than the "web app" one, agreed (I'll leave you to submit a more adequately worded answer!). But would the OP necessarily be deploying as a web app already? Aren't they just using the show method on the active spreadsheet? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface

Comment: Oops - I read too fast, had a complete brain-fart on `.show()` - my assumption was wrong.